# A vector of pointers to objects that may or may not exist

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Here's the problem: I am making a game using SFML, and I wanted to have a vector of sf::Drawable* so I could simply do windowManager.add(randomGameSprite), but the problem I have is that I want to be able to have it so I can do delete randomGameSprite without having to manually remove the pointer from the window. Is there some way to have it check to see if the object exists before trying to draw it?

I am using C++11, but the smart pointers haven't been much help in this from what I've tried. I tried using std::shared_ptr, but it keeps the drawables alive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could store [`weak_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) in your vector. A weak pointer will not keep the object alive: if all shared pointers to the object go out of scope, the weak pointer will automatically expire.

Comment: IIUC this will not work if OP's juggling bare pointers to the object and manually `delete`s it through one of those. Correct? It's not like that's a good thing to do, but from the sound of the question that's what OP does, so it's worth mentioning IMHO.

Comment: Is it worth going through the effort of converting to smart pointers? I've been trying to get them figured out, but I keep hitting snags left and right. Namely, I can't figure out how to make one pointing to an existing object that has no pointers already.

Comment: @Astrognome: I think the conversion is well worth the effort. I recommend reading up on `shared_ptr` et al - they are very easy to use once you understand how they work.

Comment: Okay, it's been a few days, but everything seems to be going smoothly. Once I got the hang of it, smart pointers are fantastic. I'm now using a std::unordered_set of weak_ptr<sf::Drawable>, although you do have to create the hash functions for it.